# Programatically change selected tab for IOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a little stuck with this one,

I have a logout button on my app and when I tap it I want to change the selected tab of my tab bar controller to the tab that's selected when the app loads up (index 0) (this should trigger the "sign in to continue" view)

***A little more context***

My app's root view is a `TabBarController` and each tab is declared like this:

```
let friends = CalendarNavigationController(rootViewController: FriendsListViewController())
    friends.title = "Friends"
    friends.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "icon_friends")
```

This is where I want to send the user after logging out, to trigger a `WelcomeViewController`

```
let myMonth = CalendarNavigationController(rootViewController: CalendarViewController())
myMonth.title = "My Month"
myMonth.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "icon_me")
```

the controllers are assigned with this line: `viewControllers = [myMonth, friends, notification, more]`

The logout button is inside a `UserManagerViewController` which is presented modally from the `SettingsViewController` (poorly named as `"more"` in the Tab Bar)

(almost there)

the button successfully calls this function when tapped:

```
@objc func doLogout(){
    print("Logout")
    do {
       // try  Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            print(self.parent?.tabBarController) <--- This is nil
            self.parent?.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.parent?.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0]
            
        }
    } catch {
        
    }
}
```

I have tried `.selectedViewController` (as you can see from my code) and also `.selectedIndex[0]`... as far as I can tell nothing seems to be happening, presumably because the `self.parent?.tabBarController` seems to be nil.

Does anybody have any ideas as to where I've gone wrong or how I might make this work?

Thanks :)

Comment: I guess that's happening because self.parent seems to be nil. Can you let me know how you are setting the parent?

Comment: I agree with what's implied by both the comment and answer (they are two different people). What I see - ad it sounds like both are saying - is you aren't really coding against the *actual* view controller hierarchy. It's hard to duplicate from the code you posted, but it sounds like it's a tab bar VC that presents one of two (or more) VCs and one of those presents a logout VC. If that's correct, you need a way for the logout VC to work with the tab bar VC, probably directly. And as posted, that's why you need delegation.

Comment: @PrateekVarshney and dfd  This makes sense, I occasionally (can't replicate it now) get a message on the log about pushing a view that's not part of the view hierarchy (on my list of things to address eventually)... that may be what's happening here, I suspect that will be a question for another time haha, I'll try Sh_Khan's answer in the mean time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
@objc func doLogout(){
    print("Logout")
    do {
        try  Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let tab = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
               tab.selectedIndex = 0 
            }
        }
    } catch {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea how to access the delegate! (will be useful in the near future) and your answer worked perfectly! :)